# Hardlinks on a ext4 samba share

Tags: linux, samba

I have a samba share (`ext4` as filesystem).

Because I found out that I am not allowed to create symlinks (with `ln -s`) I tried hard-links with `ln`.

```
$touch x
$ls -li x*
52418 -rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 0 Sep  6 21:13 x

$ln x xlink
$ls -li x*
52418 -rwxr-xr-x 2 user user 0 Sep  6 21:13 x
52424 -rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 0 Sep  6 21:13 xlink
```

There is no error output. But on the inode number you can see this is not a hardlink.

1. Why is there no error message?
2. How can I create hard links?

Comment: Do you mean to create a hardlink on a filesystem mounted via CIFS or on the filesystem backing a Samba share? The former is simply not possible, the latter should just work.

Comment: @EugenRieck I don't understand the second one. ;) But I would say I mount it via `/etc/fstab` using `cifs` as filesystem specifier in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is "Your NFS/samba client cannot tell what capabilities the underlying server / filesystem has, so it will not allow you to do 'creative' things like links."

I'm also pretty sure that `ln` and the underlying `link()` system call will both revert to a regular copy if it can't create an actual link.

But at this exact moment in time, I can't find citations for either.